# Why doesn't Declare Cursor return sqlca.sqlcode in Oracle Pro*C?

Tags: c, oracle, cursor, oracle-pro-c

Recently, I was confused with an error in my program as stated in my other question: [Strange Cursor behavior while declaring same cursor multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094110/strange-cursor-behavior-while-declaring-same-cursor-multiple-times)

Upon using a lot of `printf`s etc. I figured out that:

`EXEC SQL Declare abc Cursor for select..` doesn't change/return `sqlca.sqlcode`

`EXEC SQL Open abc;..` returns `sqlca.sqlcode`

`EXEC SQL Fetch abc into .. ; ..` returns `sqlca.sqlcode`

`EXEC SQL Close abc; ..` returns `sqlca.sqlcode`

`EXEC SQL Commit; ..` returns `sqlca.sqlcode`

I would like to understand why the declare didn't return any code because we are using `EXEC SQL` declare & I thought `EXEC SQL` always returns `sqlca.sqlcode`.

Also, is there any documentation for Oracle Pro*C that explains all this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Oracle's documentation on DEF_SQLCODE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPCC/pc_10opt.htm#LNPCC3687), the described behavior would appear to be a bug; if you have set `#include <sqlqca.h>` or `EXEC SQL INCLUDE SQLCA;`and set `DEF_SQLCODE=YES` in your code, then it should have returned a code.

Their [documentation on handling runtime errors](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPCC/pc_09err.htm#LNPCC3490) might be useful.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. As per the document you shared `You can then use SQLCODE to check the results of executable SQL statement`. I assume as Open cursor is the statement which actually executes the query, declare doesn't return the sqlca.sqlcode. It just checks the syntax & throws error during compilation if there is any issue.